# Different semantics between `char *` and `int *`

Tags: c, pointers

I want to know why declaring and assigning a `char *` versus an `int *` in C have different semantics.

All of the following code is compiled with `clang` using the flags `-Wall -Werror -std=gnu99 --pedantic`.
I am trying to understand whether the difference is something that just *is*, or whether there's some bigger difference between `int *` and `char *` that I have yet to realize.

```c
// this will compile
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char *a;
    a = "1";

    printf("a: %s\n", a);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```c
// this will not compile. It's a parallel construction, substituting char for int
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int *a;
    a = 1;

    printf("a: %d\n", a);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```c
// but this will compile
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int *a;
    int b = 1;
    a = &b;

    printf("a: %d\n", *a);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The difference isn't between `char *` and `int *`, the difference is between `"1"` and `1`.

Comment: Note that `char *a;  a = "1";` sets `a` to the *address* of the string literal `"1"`.

Comment: The main difference that I immediately think of is pointer arithmetic and array indexing.  `((char*)a)[5]` will be a different location than `((int*)a)[5]`

Comment: so the difference is that the string literal "1" is itself a reference, while the integer literal 1 is a value. There are probably more exact ways to phrase this.

Comment: For completeness, also consider `'a'` - a single character, which works like your int, `char s[]="hello"` a string in an array, `int a[] = {1,2,3,4}` which both behave the same with their respective pointers.

Comment: A more accurate portrayal of the situation would be `char *a; a = '1'; int *i; i = 1;`.

Comment: why the downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

The gist of it:

The data type of `"1"` is `char*`.  So you are assigning a `char*` to a `char*` variable.

The data type of `1` is `int`.  So you are assigning an `int` to an `int*` variable which won't work since the types don't match.

Answer (score 0):

The second example won't compile because you have -Werror on, and you're attempting to assign an integer to a pointer without a cast, which is normally just a warning.  The same would happen if you did `char* a; a='a';` because you'd be attempting to assigning a char to char*.

In terms of different semantics between pointer types - what is stored in the memory as the pointer, it's likely not going to be different, but the pointer type will affect compilation.  Mainly when it comes to pointer arithmetic, array indexing, and using pointers to aggregate (struct) types and functions.

Things start acting differently when you start using pointer arithmetic/array indexing.  For example:

```
int value = 4
char *charp = &value;
int* intp = &value;
```

These will both be valid pointers.  You'll also see different behaviors during compilation if you're working with function pointers, which you can use function call syntax with, and struct pointers, where you can access members of the referenced structure with the `->` operator.

Comment: While your example is good, it also is a bit of a trap to newcomers. Why? Because it is legal only in this constellation; if you had `char value = 4;` you would violate the strict aliasing rule on the third line. Maybe you want to expand your answer in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with a difference between array, pointer, and scalar semantics.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

The string literal `"1"` is an *array* expression of type `char [2]`.  In this context, it "decays" to an expression of type `char *`, and the value of the expression is the address of the first character of the string.  So you're assigning like to like:

```
 a = "l"; // char * = char *
```

This doesn't happen with the integer variant.  The literal `1` has type `int`, but you're trying to assign that `int` value to an `int *` object:

```
a = 1; // int * = int
```

which should trigger a diagnostic.  You can only assign an `int *` value to an `int *` object - you would need to explicitly cast the `1`:

```
a = (int *) 1;
```

which will suppress the diagnostic, but `1` is very likely *not* a valid memory address on your platform, and attempting to use it will cause problems.